# Comparing whether the aggregated measures significantly differ between overlapping samples

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, multiple-comparisons, sample, overlapping-data

Let's say that I have some marketing data split between brands:

80% of respondents use brand a
60% of respondents use brand b

This data is derived from surveys in which respondents answer questions on whether they use specific brands.

E.g.

```
   Resp    brand_a   brand_b  
|   a    |    1    |    1    |
|   b    |    0    |    0    |
|   c    |    1    |    0    |
|   d    |    1    |    1    |
|   e    |    1    |   nil   |
|   f    |   nil   |    1    |
```

Including nil values as some respondents weren't asked whether they used a brand.

Is there a *statistically correct* way of determining whether the percent usage of these two brands are significantly different or not?

Most tests rely on independent samples, however this data does not. Is there a way of manipulating the data such that it permits the use of tests (e.g. t-tests) without violating their assumptions?

Furthermore, the actual data has many different brands in which all their usage needs to be compared to each other. This, I imagine, introduces other issues of multiple comparison?

What would be the best way to proceed with this?

Comment: I did not understand in what way you are comparing "overlapping samples"? To me your task looks as comparing two paired samples, two variables, and the data are dichotomous. We usually use **McNemar** test for that (for dichotomous data, it is equivalent to **Sign** test). If you want to compare 2+ such variables at once (omnibus test, like ANOVA), use **Cochran's** test.

Comment: Hmm let me expand it a bit as some respondents did not answer the question which means that it isn't paired.

Comment: So I don't think a paired test would necessarily work right?

Comment: How can these respondents be relevant if they didn't answer? Were they asked? If yes but they refused, why so happened? Yo might consider dropping them from the analysis or, perhaps, to impute them.

Comment: You could also disregard the fact that the data are "repeated measures" and do an non-paired samples comparison, such as z-test for proportions (equivalent to Chi-square homogeneity test). But you lose power at that.

Comment: You could also make "no-response" a third category. Then your data is tritomous. For such data, I could recommend considering McNemar-Bowker test or Kappa statistic/test. The two differ in what they test.

Comment: There relevant to such a degree that they are in the data, they are essentially dropped from the percentage of one brand but not from the other (where they gave a response). They just weren't given that question and therefore couldn't checkbox it. So a z-test would be the best way to proceed in comparing the usage of one brand to another?